# Can I restart a Cloud Composer Environment?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, airflow, google-cloud-composer

I'm using `Google Cloud` composer for a few days now mainly to move data from MySQL to BigQuery and it was working fine.

At some point, it stopped working:

- Running tasks run for a very long time and then fail
- Tasks don't start
- New dags have the comment `This DAG seems to be existing only locally. The master scheduler doesn't seem to be aware of its existence`

I've cleaned all the DAG runs and tasks instances using the Airflow web UI and still doesn't work.

Is there a way to restart the environment without losing the results of finished tasks?
Is there any other way to get the Airflow running manually?

Comment: I'm seeing the same thing, When I try `resetdb` I get `ERROR: gcloud crashed (TypeError): 'NoneType' object is not iterable`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot stop/restart a cloud composer environment. And till date the metadata DB is associated with the composer environment, hence deleting this environment would delete everything associated with that task.

Comment: How can I point it to the GCS with my DAGs? 
Will this also keep the DAG Runs history?

Comment: @AryJazz I have updated my answer. You won't be able to keep the DAG runs history. https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/concepts/cloud-storage - this is the link that shows what you can copy paste to the new environment or bucket associated with the new environment.

Answer (score 5):

This post is over a year old, but it might help others. To answer your 2 questions:

1. **How to restart Composer environment**
   Each time you are adding a Python package or an environment variable into Composer, this will restart the whole environment installing what needs to be added. So a workaround to restart Composer environment is to add a *dummy* environment variable. 
   Follow these steps:

   - go to your composer instance in GCP
   - ENVIRONMENT VARIABLE tabs
   - Edit, add your environment variable and Submit
2. **How to run Airflow manually**
   You can also access Airflow via Composer command line:
   https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/gcloud-installation

I hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

Edit and Submit new value in Composer Environment by Get to your Composer Instance in GCP -> Edit/Add value in Environment Variable tab -> Submit.

This will restart the whole environment.